# GeneratedMethodAccessor from JVM_DefineClass loaded 10k times cause oom

Tags: java, jvm, metaspace

[image]

added "-verbose:class" in jvm paramerter, and got 10k times log like below,
"Loaded sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10004 from **JVM_DefineClass**"

do I have any way to find the origin class and what is the root method of my application caused this?

I know "GeneratedMethodAccessor### are classes generated at runtime by the reflection implementation to call methods and constructors", but I don't what is the specific method or class loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) can help to find where these MethodAccessors are generated.

Run

```
./profiler.sh -d 120 -e sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate -f report.html <javaPID>
```

This will start recording for 120 seconds. All generated MethodAccessors for calling `Method.invoke` and `Constructor.newInstance` will be captured and saved as a Flame Graph report under `report.html`.

The Flame Graph shows the number of generated accessors with the stack traces of their origin:

[image: Reflection Flame Graph]

Alternatively to attaching the profiler in runtime, you can start Java with the profiler enabled from the very beginning:

```
java -agentpath:/path/to/libasyncProfiler.so=start,event=sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate,file=report.html -jar <your application>
```

Comment: I use this way to get the Flame Graph, but the number of the GeneratedMethodAccessor is discontinuous, many JVM_DefineClass is lost. And I found some of the are generated by "org/springframework/web/method/support/InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke", but When I try to reproduce it in my local, it doesn't happen.

Comment: @lixu You may similarly profile `event=JVM_DefineClass` (works in JDK 8 and 11, but not newer), but I expect the results will be the same.

Comment: Also note that MethodAccessors are generated after 15 reflective invocations of the method. If you call `Method.invoke` just once, you won't see it in the above Flame Graph.